# How do I set a rendered item as a state in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to set the state inside the `render()` or would I have to do it while `fetching`? I haven't found an similar questions to mine probably because I am not asking the right question, but I hope this makes sense. Here is my code:

```
<FlatList

           data={ this.state.newimage}

           ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}


           renderItem={({item}) => <View>
             //Want to set item.id as a state
             <Text>{item.id}</Text>
             </View>
             />
```

And if needed here is my `fetch`:

```
fetch(`https://www.example.com/React/images.php`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
}).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {

     this.setState({
        dataSource: responseJson, //<-- This is uneeded data
        newimage:  responseJson[0].image.map(item => ({ ...item, progress: new Animated.Value(0), unprogress: new Animated.Value(1) }))
        //mapping is only for animating the likes, adds a unique progress to the json array
       },function() {

       });



}).catch((error) => {
  //console.error(error);
});
```

All of the JSON code:

```
[{"id":"16","first_name":"Bob","last_name":"Jones","username":"HiBill","image":[{"id":"10","images":"Emerson live in the sunshine swim in the sea drink the wild air.jpg","note":"Hello","tags":"sunshine"},{"id":"12","images":"on top of the mountains and beneath the stars.jpg","note":"Ah peaceful ","tags":"mountains"},{"id":"35","images":"8D11AE92-270E-4F98-846A-B9BED75AD550.jpeg","note":"Just be yourself \ud83d\udc4c","tags":"Happy"}
```

Comment: You shouldn't set the state during render, as that will cause a new render. So maybe try to explain better what you are after? Maybe you want something like a `ref` rather?

Comment: @Icepickle I hope this makes sense, but basically I am forcing a re-fetch from the `.php` file everytime I click the button. It adds +1 or -1 depending if I already clicked it or not. (Think of a like button). I thought it would be easier and quicker to just get the existing `item.id` turn it into a `this.state` and do the math in React Native rather than `.php`. Ex. If I clicked the button then `this.state.id = this.state.id + 1`. Something like that.

Comment: Where do you get `item` in your `renderItem` function?

Comment: @devserkan I get it from the `.php` file. It is `json_encoded` from the query.

Comment: Can't you set the item as a state in a suitable lifecycle method?

Comment: @devserkan I can, but I don't know how to get the `id` items from the JSON array. I tried this: `this.state.newimage[0].id`, but it does not work.

Comment: I think you are off a bit, since you mention you want it to capture likes. It doesn't sound like you wish to increase the id, but rather to increase the likes, which sounds like a nice state changes on your object

Comment: @Icepickle Yes, I just used `id` as an example. So would `this.state` be good for what I am trying to accomplish? What I have right now, which is just a refetch, is just a little slower.

Comment: How does `responseJson` look like after fetch complete? I mean before the `setState` step.

Comment: @devserkan it looks like this before the state is set: `[{"image":[]}]`

Comment: So, still looks like a JSON. Forgive my ignorance but should not `fetch`'s `.json()` handle this? Also, after setting your state when you `console.log` `this.state.newimage` what do you see? You can do the logging in `setState`'s callback function or in the `render` method.

Comment: @devserkan when I console log, I get the same result in my question above. (edited in JSON). If I could gather `id` from the state(`this.state.newimage`), that would also be great!

Comment: You need to state what you're trying to do to make it easier for us to give you a suggestions but it sounds like you should make the render item into it's own component containing its own states.

Comment: Then `this.state.newimage[0].id` should work. See: https://codesandbox.io/s/x9lr684n4o

Comment: @MattAft I just want to put all `id`'s (item.id) into `this.state`. It behaves the same just being called like this: `this.state.ids`. Also @deverskan, this kinda works, but it does work for my code where it does all of the `ids`

Comment: Here, I will give the full code in the question...

Comment: So, you want to keep all objects in `image` array of your JSON, then somehow with a button increment the `id` of objects?

Answer (score 0):

I am only guessing, but I believe you want to have one component that owns the state, and some of your other components will render the state, and use some click events to update the state

In the below code, the `BreedLikeList` is the owner of the state, and makes sure that the likes are part of the data send to the `List` component, a third component, called `breedView` is only there to render the single breed, and forward any clicks made to the given event, which is located on the `BreedLikeList`.

Once the state gets updated the `BreedLikeList` renders it's state, which will renew the single items.

If I got the question wrong based on the question or the comments, let me know what you are missing.

The code is not in react-native, but I am guessing state handling isn't that different from the default react state.

The below code will not save changes to the state, as long as the page isn't refreshed, the likes will be there, upon new load, that data will disappear. How you handle state in your app, is clearly a decision you still have to make

```js
// small list component, just group some of the data to the given itemTemplate
class List extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { items, itemTemplate, onItemClicked } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="list">
        { items && items.map( (item, key) => React.createElement( itemTemplate, { onItemClicked, item, key } ) ) }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// a functional component that shows the current breeds, and if any likes, how many are there
// through click event, the likes get increased
const breedView = ( { item, onItemClicked } ) => {
  const { breed, likes } = item;
  return <span className="breed" onClick={ () => onItemClicked( breed ) }>
    { breed }
    { likes > 0 && <span className="like">+ { likes }</span> }
  </span>;
};

// class component that loads the data and keeps the likes
// upon state changes rerenders so that likes are visible for the users
// this state will re-initialize as soon as the page gets reloaded
class BreedLikeList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      breeds: [],
      liked: {}
    };
    this.onBreedLiked = this.onBreedLiked.bind( this );
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.mounted = true;
    fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all')
      .then( response => response.json() )
      .then( json => this.mounted && this.setState( { breeds: Object.keys( json.message ) } ) );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false;
  }
  onBreedLiked( breed ) {
    this.setState( { liked: { ...this.state.liked, [breed]: (this.state.liked[breed] || 0) + 1 } } );
  }
  render() {
    const { breeds, liked } = this.state;
    return <List 
      items={ breeds.map( breed => ({ breed: breed, likes: liked[breed] || 0 }) ) }
      itemTemplate={ breedView }
      onItemClicked={ this.onBreedLiked }
    />;
  }
}

// render everything
const target = document.querySelector('#container');
ReactDOM.render( <BreedLikeList />, target );
```

```css
.breed {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
}
.breed:hover {
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}
.like {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: small;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script id="react" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.js"></script>
<script id="react-dom" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I appreciate all of this and this will definitely be in great use, but is it possible we can discuss in the room chat?

Comment: @LaneyWilliams sure, we can chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177978/react-native-and-state